# How to stop positioned text objects from moving inside Stack as text changes across devices?

Tags: flutter, dart

Objective: I want a TextButton to be bisected by a Container in a Stack.
Problem: The size of the TextButton changes across devices, causing an unwanted offset. See the first photo.

[image: not pixel perfect on web]
[image: this looks good on mobile]

Below is a minimum reproducible example in which I use a static integer offset to position the TextButton. I also attempted to specify the TextButton's parent Container's width and height in an attempt to ensure my positional offset was the same each time, but overconstraining the TextButton caused odd reactions like this: [image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: '):',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: '):'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool buttonToggled = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 30, 0, 0),
          child: Stack(
            clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
            alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                //outline
                height: 135,
                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 20, 20),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.purpleAccent, width: 1),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                  shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                  color: Colors.green,
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                  left: 40,
                  top: 3,
                  child: Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 0),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(7, 0, 7, 0),
                      height: 30,
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      child: Center(
                          child: TextButton(
                        child: Text(
                          buttonToggled ? '+ End Date and Time ' : '— End Date and Time',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.start, //aligment
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            buttonToggled = !buttonToggled;
                          });
                        },
                      )))),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: what's  your problem?   the blue container size changed on different device ? or text size changed ?

Comment: I do keep all of size, inset, margin the same, but the font size seems to change by device.

Comment: you can setup font size then.

Comment: There's a Theme  that may different on different devices. `If the style's "inherit" property is true, the style will be merged with the closest enclosing [DefaultTextStyle]`

Comment: That's perhaps a fix, but then the button likely wouldn't grow with screen size.

Answer (score 0):

if you setup same size, inset, margin, it should not be different in different device.

have a try with  `TextStyle(color: Colors.white, inherit: false)`